# Is there any reason why you'd want a space between the variable and the increment/decrement operator?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning how to write HTML5 games using the Phaser framework. One of the things I'm doing as part of the learning process is studying and adapting examples I find on the web. The example I'm working through right now is a [4096/2048/Threes clone](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/03/30/play-4096-my-html5-take-on-2048-game-built-with-phaser-3-and-get-the-source-code-for-free/). In the sample source code I saw a strange pattern. The author was consistently putting a space in between the variable and the increment/decrement operator when manipulating a certain variable. For example below are lines 248 to 268 from their source code:

```
moveTile: function(tile, row, col, distance, changeNumber){
    this.movingTiles ++; // example gap 
    this.tweens.add({
        targets: [tile.tileSprite],
        x: this.tileDestination(col, COL),
        y: this.tileDestination(row, ROW),
        duration: gameOptions.tweenSpeed * distance,
        onComplete: function(tween){
            tween.parent.scene.movingTiles --; // example gap
            if(changeNumber){
                tween.parent.scene.transformTile(tile, row, col);
            }
            if(tween.parent.scene.movingTiles == 0){
                tween.parent.scene.scoreText.text = tween.parent.scene.score.toString();
                tween.parent.scene.bestScoreText.text = tween.parent.scene.bestScore.toString();
                tween.parent.scene.resetTiles();
                tween.parent.scene.addTile();
            }
        }
    })
},
```

To my surprise this still incremented/decremented the `this.movingTiles` variable. Since the developer consistently did this when interacting with the `this.movingTiles` variable I believe it must be a deliberate choice. Furthermore, when setting up for loops the developer doesn't put the gap between the variable and the increment/decrement operator. Which means it was *targeted and consistent* behavior.

The Mozilla docs on the [increment/decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) only mention the difference between prepending and appending the increment/decrement operator. They don't discuss adding a gap. I'm reasonably comfortable in in javascript but I'm certainly no expert. So I'm asking you is there a method to their madness or is it just a strange idiosyncrasy?

---

I'd like to make it clear that I mean no disrespect to the original developer. His examples are invaluable learning tools for me. I just want to make sure I'm understanding the nuances.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm not asking what is better. I'm asking is there any difference. "Which is better" is a subjective matter of taste. "Is there any difference" is an objective and valid programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [spec (ES6)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-white-space) on white space:

> White space code points are used to improve source text readability and to **separate tokens** (indivisible lexical units) from each other, **but are otherwise insignificant**.

In case of the code you refer, the tokens involved are the `++` punctuator, and the identifier names.

---

To answer your question:

> So I'm asking you is there a method to their madness or is it just a strange idiosyncrasy?

There is no functional difference, it is purely a matter of taste.

---

Keep in mind that this holds true only until the semicolons are explicitly added to the code (by the programmer). If that's not the case, automatic semicolon insertion comes into the picture, and in certain cases there *might* be a functional difference. You can read about that here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-examples-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion

Comment: @Erik With Nisarg's excellent answer, the question is no longer seem off-topic. BTW, why the 24 to 48 delay, you can (and should) accept the answer right away if it does answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Assignment test

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
i++;
j  ++;

console.log(i === j);
```

Return test

```
j = 0;
x1 = j++;

j = 0;
x2 = j  ++;

console.log(x1 === x2);
```

Both the tests logs out `true`.

Comment: The first example edited. You can prove the concept using them.